# Как вызвать меню выбора лишь на несколько секунд?

Tags: python

Имеется код python:

```
from pyfzf.pyfzf import FzfPrompt

fzf = FzfPrompt()

select = [item1, item2]
sel = fzf.prompt(select)
nsel = sel[0]
```

Только, надо вызвать это меню лишь на несколько секунд, и в случае отсутствия выбора пользователя, закрыть. Как это вообще сделать?